# After getting the connection from Glassfish Connection Pool and use it, should I close it right after?

Tags: java, glassfish-3, connection-pooling

This is the way for me to get my connection

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("glassfish_pool_res");
connection = ds.getConnection();
```

After I use the connection, like this:

```
CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall(call_statement);
...
cs.execute();
```

should I do `cs.close()` and `connection.close()` right after?
Is that the right way to close the connection to avoid memory leaks?
I'm developing a web application btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. That is right way to do.

```
close()  returns connection to connection pool
```

Comment: Hmm, I've done that, but there is still a memory leak I guess. Especially when I redeploy the project repeatedly, glassfish memory usage keeps increasing to the point where it reaches max memory usage. Any idea?